# Report layout not as expected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

When my report contains only 3 records the report layout printed is fine but this is what happens when there are 5 records:

[image]

However my expected result should be like this:

[image]

As you can the Totals should appear at the bottom not in the middle. Mind you with 3 records the report prints fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping on **something** but it is hard to see what exactly using the examples shown.

Your totals are showing in at the end of whatever grouping you are using. If you are grouping by the transaction date ensure it is a date and not a date time column.